# Laravel project deployment gives the HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel

Before you assume, I did read ALL other posts on this problem and I was unable to find a solution to my problem.

So the thing is, however and wherever i upload my files and folders on my web host i get the same result giving me the "currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500". I'm using the 000webhostapp.

So I uploaded the project in my root directory "/", content of the public to the public_html project, and it gave me the text above. Then I tried moving my whole project into the public_html(public was its own directory inside public_html) and it gave me the same result. I've tried some solutions with .htaccess file but whatever I tried won't make it work. In my localhost project is installed somewhat like this "htdocs/kola/..", but on the web hosting it is just in the root, no other dir(that's something I think might help but I'm unable to use). So after 30 hours of trying and reuploading the project 5 times,  still can't make it work and I'd be rather grateful if someone could even try to help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to be sure: you do have an `APP_KEY` in your environment variables?

Comment: Hi, im not sure about that. Where should i look for that one?

Comment: You can put in a `.env` file in your project root, or find out how your host allows you to set env variables.

Comment: But that might not be the issue though--the 500 error page you see...is it apache's or Laravel's?

Comment: It't apaches http://prntscr.com/is0w7k

Comment: Hmmm...can you view the apache logs? The're usually in `/var/log/apache2` or something similar

Comment: sadly i cant as im using 000webhost

Comment: Have you also confirmed PHP versions are compatible?

Comment: Here's a bit of debugging: place an `index.php` file with the contents `<?= phpinfo() ?>` in the `public_html`. Then visit your site. It should output your PHP information. Does that work?

Comment: yes i have, im using the new version of laravel (5.4 i think) and the php version on the server us 7.1 (7.1.3 is the laravel recomendation but can this realy be the problem?)

Comment: and the phpinfo does work, it outputs the php config (7.1.14 php version)

Comment: Are all your composer requirements installed?

Comment: Is there any way i could check that as im not even sure anymore

Comment: Run `composer install` in the root of your project.

Comment: As i cant use composer on the webhost, i have to run it locally first so does it change any of the files in the laravel's vendor folder(it has over 6k files and it takes about an hour to reupload)

Comment: Also, this is the output after the command http://prntscr.com/is1e1b

Comment: Then everything seems to be installed correctly.

Comment: Theoretically, the following should work: 1. upload your project to the root directory. 2. Move files from `public` to `public_html`. 3. Change any references to public to point to public_html (for instance, in .htaccess). 4. Change permissions of storage and cache folder (make sure they're writable by the server). Also, yes, the PHP compatibility could be an issue. Check your Laravel version. Also, don't forget your `vendor` folder

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info you gave but i tried all of that multiple times and neither once did reuploading change anything. Possibly got any other ideas?

Comment: This could be so very many different things (apache, php, permissions, php extensions, mysql drivers, laravel configuration, etc...). Since you don't have access to the logs it will be maddening to debug. Your host seems to have a history of mod_rewrite frustrations: https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/how-to-make-mod-rewrite-rules-working-14 so you can try adding `RewriteBase /` to your apache config. You'll want to try to get logs by following this suggestion: https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/where-is-my-error-log-hosting/65859/2 and let us know what ends up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to get to the root of your folder ... ie `/home/` and create a folder for your project.  Then move the all the contents of your project into this folder except the public folder.  Now go to the `public_html` folder and add all the contents of the public folder there.

Update your `index.php` as below:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../(name of your root folder)/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../(name of your root folder)/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Configure the `.env` file and have the right database configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Need not to create new dir. Just delete the content of index.php file and paste the above code and replace your (name of your root folder) with public_html.